# Another Traceback Error When I Run My Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a new Traceback Error When, I run my Python Code. It appears to be to do with the very last ) Parentheses, also maybe the last ] in my Code.

```
((df['Location'].str.contains('- Display')) & 
                df['Lancaster'] != 'L' & 
                df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
                df['Spitfire'] == 'SS' &
                df['Hurricane'] != 'H'))
              )]
```

And here is the Traceback Error I get :

```
        File "<ipython-input-5-6d53e7e5ec10>", line 31
        )
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my latest, whole Code John S, that works. I will let you know, if I get
more issues, many thanks for your help :

`import pandas as pd
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

```
res = requests.get("http://web.archive.org/web/20070701133815/http://www.bbmf.co.uk/june07.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = df[1]
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
df = df.iloc[2:]
df.head(15)

display = df[(df['Location'].str.contains('- Display')) & (df['Dakota'].str.contains('D')) & (df['Spitfire'].str.contains('S')) & (df['Lancaster'] != 'L')]     
display </code>
```

Comment: You're (at-least) missing a closing `]`. If you're still getting syntax errors I would recommend printing this out and (by-hand) identifying each pair of `(),[],{}`. At the end you should find which ones are mis-matched.

Comment: Thankyou SyntaxVoid, is there a Python Utility, that could find any mismatches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to many brackets

```
((df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
  df['Lancaster'] == '' & 
  df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
  df['Spitfire'] == 'SS' & 
  df['Hurricane'] == ''))
```

You needed to remove a ')' after each ('- Display') it looks like you will still have some problems with sorting through your data. But this should get you past your syntax error.

Look at this online version so see my edits.

https://onlinegdb.com/Skceaucyr

Comment: Which brackets do I need to remove John S ?

Comment: The final two closing brackets  "]" and ")". See my code snippet.

Comment: Yes I have removed them, and when I run my code, I still get the same Traceback Error.

Comment: Update your post to share more of your code then. So I can see what those other brackets are for.

Comment: I rejected your edit because you tried to edit my answer. You should edit your own post.

Comment: Sorry John, my mistake, I hadn't noticed it was your post, many apologies

Comment: Check out that link I sent you, It should get you past your syntax error.

Comment: Many thanks for this John, I am going to have my tea shortly, but will get back to you later, with feedback. I have been using a utility recently, called Jupyter Notebook on the internet. Eddie

Comment: Not a problem Eddie. If you feel like my solution has adequately helped you get past your syntax error, please mark the question as solved.

Comment: Hi John, I get a different Traceback Error now :- I will edit my post, to show it.

Comment: I believe it is in df = df.iloc[2:]. Because it is not expecting the : I would print(df) so you can see the data. Then try to parse it differently.

Comment: How do I do that John ?

Comment: I was wrong you just need some closing brackets ' )' and ']' see how my online compiler is formatted

Comment: Still getting a Traceback Error, sorry for this John I appreciate your help, I am stumped.

Comment: The problem is in you definition of Southport. It does not make sense. You need to refactor it. Or open a new issue seeking help on how to.

Comment: Hi John S, I have sorted the issue out, with no more errors, for the time being. I have posted, my current working Code, and I will let you know if I need more help, many thanks. Eddie

Comment: How do I do that John S ?

Comment: Sorted now John S, I have clicked the check mark, next to your answer. Sorry I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add ")]" in the end. So you variable southport will be now

```
Southport = df[
    (
        ((df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] != 'L' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'S' & 
        df['Hurricane'] == 'H'))
    )
] | df[
    (
        ((df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] != 'L' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'S' &
        df['Hurricane'] != 'H'))
    )
] | df[
    (
        ((df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] != 'L' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'SS' &
        df['Hurricane'] != 'H'))
     )]
```

Comment: Hi Anmol, I still get a Traceback Error, when I make that alteration, and run the Code.

Comment: This Problem, was sorted out, the other day Anmol. I changed the Code.